# Add and resize DIV's on the same space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I want to make a bar where I can add multiple child DIVs (Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdWsq.jpg). 
I am using jQuery, jQuery UI and Bootstrap. Plus a few plugins.
The div (or span) system could look something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" id="1"></div>
    <div class="child" id="2"></div>
    <div class="child" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

And the "Add div" could look like this:

```
$('parent').append('<div class="child" id="4"></div>');
```

And I don't know how the rest jQuery / javascript could look.
One of the biggest problems I have, that other threats here don't solve is that I want to have this working on mobile too. Maybe using Hammer.js

I have been looking for this quite some time, but if this already have been posted, I'm sorry

**UPDATE:** If I didn't said it clearly enough, you have to drag the divs. Like you can with this plugin http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqDnR/, but the total width shall stay the same (the DIV's, that are not being resized have to get smaller)

Example: You have one bar on 600px. There are 3 child DIV's, where each is 200px. Then you resize one of them, so it is 300px. Then the other ones is 150px each

Comment: Are you saying you want a bar where, when you add a new child div, all of the other divs will automatically resize and be distributed evenly? How will new divs be added? Based on an event?

Comment: Yes. When a function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="addChild" value="Add Child"/>
<div id="parent" class="parentClass">

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var idGen = 0;
$("#addChild").on("click",function(){
    $("#parent").append("<div id='" + idGen++ + "' class='childClass'>Child Div</div>");
});
```

CSS:

```
.childClass
{
    background-color:#b0c4de;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid;
    padding:4px;
}
.parentClass
{
    background-color:green;
    width:500px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rrdyw/

I haven't tested but I am sure this would work on mobile as well.

Comment: I've made a clarification. The total width stay the same, but the chld DIV's can be resized. I find it pretty difficult to describe.

Comment: [live](http://api.jquery.com) has been deprecated for quite some time. It doesn't exist as of jQuery 1.9. *Please* stop using it. More importantly, please stop suggesting it to others to use...

Comment: My bad, changing it to on.